# Does the Stack Overflow flair contain encoded data?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flair

Is there any data encoded in the picture (like name, account, website, score) that can be decoded by scanning the [Stack Overflow flair](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/) with a scanner app (Android or iPhone)?

Comment: You tagged this as meta and didn't think that you should _ask_ it on http://meta.stackoverflow.com ???

Comment: @Oded: You're right, it's *incredible* that this 56-point user didn't know that meta-questions go to an entirely separate site.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - seeing as the `meta` link is at the top of _every_ SO page...

Comment: And there's another link to meta [in the Ask Question page itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)...

Comment: If you play it backwards, it tries to parse HTML using regular expressions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just generated based on the hash of your email (or IP address if you didn't set any). There are an extremely large number of possibilities.

See http://blog.gravatar.com/2008/04/22/identicons-monsterids-and-wavatars-oh-my/.

Comment: Brilliant, the question is about the avatars, not about the flair per se! Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing like that, just what you see on it.

Are you thinking of [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)? There is none in these images.

Comment: Given the reference to scanning with smartphones, I guess it's more about some sort of QR codes?

Comment: No, not about steganography (horrible word) - more about 3d barcodes.